# Making a finite automata

Tags: automata, finite-automata

How can I make a finite automaton which does not end in string ab.

With the alphabet a,b

I made 3 states. For the first one it is accepting states and thus accept the empty string.

So here is a table I made. State 1 is initial state

```
        input   goes to state input goes to state
```

State 1

```
         b       1             a      2
```

state 2

```
          b       3             a       2
```

state 3

```
            b       3              a      3
```

But will it work?

Comment: Draw a picture of it, test it on some words. Then, if you are happy with it, prove that it is correct.

Comment: You can use http://madebyevan.com/fsm/ to draw automata easily

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is your suggested automaton, if I understand your transitions correctly (initial state is 1)

[image]

This automaton will only accept $\epsilon$, and words consisting of a number of $b$'s

**Hints to make one that accepts your language:**

Make sure that it accepts $\epsilon, a, b$ and make sure that you "move away" from accepting states when seeing a $b$ after an $a$ (keep in mind that $aabb$ is also a string in the language, i.e the second $b$ should make the machine go to an accepting state).